# I am writing a javascript function to return the Fibonacci of any given number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a javascript function to return the Fibonacci of any given number in an array. that array must always begin with [0, 1, ]. my function works for o, 1, and 2 but doesn’t work for 3. my code is incomplete, it returns "undefined. please find attached a screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqTOq.png).

```
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
//Do NOT change any of the code above 
    
    //Write your code here:
    var output;
    if (n===0){
        output = [0]
    }

    else if (n===1){
        output = [1];
    }

    else if (n===2){
        output = [0,1];
    }
    
    else{
        for(var i=0; i<=n.length; i++){
            n = [];
            let firstTerm = 0;
            let secondTerm = 1;
            let nextTerm = firstTerm+secondTerm
            n= nextTerm.push();
            output = n[i]
        }

    }

   
    
    
    //Return an array of fibonacci numbers starting from 0.
    return output;
//Do NOT change any of the code below 
}
 fibonacciGenerator(3);
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: "n" is a number; what do you think its "length" property will be? You set it to an array *inside* the "for" loop. In general it's rarely a good idea to re-use parameters like this. Unrelated, but it's generally better to stick to "let" and "const" and skip "var" altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has a number of errors. After fixing these, I also discovered some logic errors. In summary, you have to save the `firstterm` as the `secondterm` with each iteration, and the `secondterm` as the `old-firstterm + the old-secondterm`.

Here is how this would be done:

```js
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
//Do NOT change any of the code above 
    
    //Write your code here:
    var output = [],firstTerm = 0,secondTerm = 1;
    if (n===0){
        output = [0]
    }

    else if (n===1){
        output = [1];
    }

    else if (n===2){
        output = [0,1];
    }
    
    else{
        for(var i=0; i<=n; i++){
            output.push(firstTerm);
            let nextTerm = firstTerm+secondTerm; 
            firstTerm = secondTerm; 
            secondTerm = nextTerm;
        }

    }

   
    
    
    //Return an array of fibonacci numbers starting from 0.
    return output;
//Do NOT change any of the code below 
}


let count = 5;
console.log("Here are the next " + count + " numbers after 0:");
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(count));
```